# Android RestTemplate, Could not read JSON: No content to map due to end-of-input

Tags: android, resttemplate

I'm posting a request to create a resource on the server side.
The server answers with an 201 Created status code and an empty content.

This create the following error in the client side:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: No content to map due to end-of-input
        at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@4354aff0; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
        at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@4354aff0; line: 1, column: 1]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:126)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:147)
        at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:76)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:484)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:439)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:317)
        at com.test.requests.favorites.PostFavoriteRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(PostFavoriteRequest.java:30)
        at com.test.requests.favorites.PostFavoriteRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(PostFavoriteRequest.java:10)
        at com.octo.android.robospice.request.CachedSpiceRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(CachedSpiceRequest.java:45)
        at com.octo.android.robospice.request.DefaultRequestRunner.processRequest(DefaultRequestRunner.java:149)
        at com.octo.android.robospice.request.DefaultRequestRunner$1.run(DefaultRequestRunner.java:216)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
```

How can I handle responses with empty content?

I already tried the following as response type class:

```
return getRestTemplate().postForObject(url, httpEntity, String.class);

return getRestTemplate().postForObject(url, httpEntity, Void.class);

return getRestTemplate().postForObject(url, httpEntity, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I will answer my own question as this might help someone in the future.

Using RestTemplate.postForObject expect a non empty result (different from Void or null) and directly uses an `HttpMessageConverterExtractor`.
But you can use RestTemplate.exchange that uses a `ResponseEntityResponseExtractor` instead of directly using a `HttpMessageConverterExtractor` which the above method does and the `ResponseEntityResponseExtractor` does the following check before creating a response extractor.

From the RestTemplate source code:

```
private class ResponseEntityResponseExtractor<T> implements ResponseExtractor<ResponseEntity<T>> {

    private final HttpMessageConverterExtractor<T> delegate;

    public ResponseEntityResponseExtractor(Class<T> responseType) {
        if (responseType != null && !Void.class.equals(responseType)) {
            this.delegate = new HttpMessageConverterExtractor<T>(responseType, getMessageConverters());
        } else {
            this.delegate = null;
        }
    }

    public ResponseEntity<T> extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        if (delegate != null) {
            T body = delegate.extractData(response);
            return new ResponseEntity<T>(body, response.getHeaders(), response.getStatusCode());
        }
        else {
            return new ResponseEntity<T>(response.getHeaders(), response.getStatusCode());
        }
    }
}
```